# How to access structure variable defined in another structure?

Tags: c

I have following structure

```
typedef struct List_Node {
     struct File_Descriptor *data;
     char *key;
    struct List_Node *next;
}List_Node;
```

Now I inserted some values into the both the structures and want to access the data of type File_descriptor. How to do this?

I tried this

```
struct List_Node *ln1;
printf("%s", ln1.File_Descriptor->data);
```

but it is giving error

```
error: request for member ‘error: File_Descriptor’ in something not a structure or union`
```

Comment: There is no structure inside the structure; only a pointer. (which could point to an incomplete type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want:

```
struct List_Node *ln1;
printf("%s", ln1->data);
```

`struct File_Descriptor` is the type. `data` is the struct member name.

Also though the `printf` format looks entirely wrong. Not sure what you're trying to do there. `%s` is string, and `data` certainly doesn't look like a string.

Comment: It can't be a good idea to use `"%s"` with an argument of type `struct File_Descriptor*`

Comment: @aschepler Indeed. Added that to my answer.

Comment: I made so many mistakes in my answer which you kindly corrected I just deleted it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing the type name with the variable name. In order to access the `data` member of the `List_Node` struct, you use the following:

```
struct List_Node *ln1; // initialize this
printf("%s", ln1->data);
```

Don't forget that you first have to initialize the `ln1` pointer to point to a valid memory location before dereferencing it.